# How to present UITableView only in certain condition over UIViewController Similar to Google Map Search Option

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to implement place search of google maps same as it is presented in Google maps application

I was hoping to present `UITableView` only for certain conditions. How could i achieve that.

**First sample of google maps apps**

[image]

I have achieved following
**Things I have achieved so far**

[image]

How can I achieve same as First sample of google maps apps.  I know how to populate the places using place Api of google maps. I am having trouble only in design case i.e how to present them over the map view.

Comment: No need to create two different ViewControllers. You can put two UITableViews in single View Controller. Or if it don't fit into your screen You can use scrollView.

Comment: @AshokLondhe can you check updated questions

Comment: Can you define what are your "certain conditions"?

Comment: I know how to populate the places using place Api of google maps. I am having trouble only in design case i.e how to present them over the map view.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show table view in some condition then when you get that condition just add delegate and data source to tableview and add it on your tableview. and when you don't want to show it then remove it from super view else hide it.

I hope it will help you in that.